# How to log AMQP commands in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I log all AMQP commands that go through RabbitMQ broker including service commands like `basic.ack`, `confirm.select` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Java client library `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.5.4` contains `Tracer` tool that works as a standalone proxy between your client and broker. It logs all AMQP commands that go through it to `System.out`.

It's described here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html

Here's an example of its output:

```
1441190584927: <Tracer-0> ch#1 -> {#method<channel.open>(out-of-band=), null, ""}
1441190584968: <Tracer-0> ch#1 <- {#method<channel.open-ok>(channel-id=), null, ""}
1441190585008: <Tracer-0> ch#1 -> {#method<confirm.select>(nowait=false), null, ""}
1441190585047: <Tracer-0> ch#1 <- {#method<confirm.select-ok>(), null, ""}
1441190585090: <Tracer-0> ch#1 -> {#method<basic.publish>(ticket=0, exchange=node.confirm.publish, routing-key=, mandatory=false, immediate=false), #contentHeader<basic>(content-type=string/utf8, content-encoding=null, headers=null, delivery-mode=2, priority=null, correlation-id=null, reply-to=null, expiration=null, message-id=null, timestamp=null, type=null, user-id=null, app-id=null, cluster-id=null), "some message"}
1441190585128: <Tracer-0> ch#1 <- {#method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'node.confirm.publish' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40), null, ""}
```

Answer (score -1):

you'll need to modify the rabbimq config. see [this page for configuration settings](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).

specifically, you'll want to set something like "info" or "debug" for whatever you're interested in:

```
[
  {log_levels, [
    {channel, debug},
    {connection, debug}
  ]}
].
```

From that page, look for `log_levels` and you'll find this configuration information:

> Controls the granularity of logging. The value is a list of log event category and log level pairs.
>
> The level can be one of 'none' (no events are logged), 'error' (only errors are logged), 'warning' (only errors and warning are logged), 'info' (errors, warnings and informational messages are logged), or 'debug' (errors, warnings, informational messages and debugging messages are logged).
>
> At present there are four categories defined. Other, currently uncategorized, events are always logged.
>
> The categories are:
>
> - channel - for all events relating to AMQP channels
> - connection - for all events relating to network connections
> - federation - for all events relating to federation
> - mirroring - for all events relating to mirrored queues
>
> Default: [{connection, info}]

Comment: I tried to put `{log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {channel, debug}]}` in my rabbitmq.config but I don't see AMQP commands logged. I've checked that my config file is used by setting log level to `none` and observing that nothing is logged.

What am I missing?